# How can a program print its own source code without reading any file

Tags: java

I've to write a code that outputs its own source code, but I am not allowed to read it from the file.

This is what we got from the teacher:

```
public class SelfPrint {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print(getMyText());
  }
  private static String programText [] = {
      ....
  };
  private static String getMyText() {
  }
  
}
```

Comment: `is the syntax of the programText method right?` <- its not a method, its a private static string array.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is your task? Do you need to print out the `programText` array (and also execute it?) or do you need to get the source code of the whole `SelfPrint` class without reading the file from the file system?

Comment: Yes i have to get the source code oh the whole class without reading it from the file. I don't even know if that is possible. We got this task in Theoretical computer science and wondering if i have to solve by using "formal language".. something like: the keyword public has to follow with (static | void | String | int .....)

Comment: It is not possible to get the source code of a class without reading it from a file.  A compiled (i.e. .class) file does not contain (for example) the comments, the original indentation, etc that were in the .java file. And it is not always possible to correctly reconstruct the original Java statements from the bytecodes.

Comment: @StephenC I read about this in the 1970s, as a puzzle. Start by imagining code that contains a copy of itself. But, then you have an "infinite regression" problem: Each copy will contain another copy. The puzzle is how to get it to print its own code and avoid infinite regression.

Comment: Ah.  That puzzle.  The OP has misstated it. The actual problem is to *generate* (write) its own source code.  Not "read" it.   (It is called a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

`getMyText` has three for statements. The first one prints the first 5 lines of the program. The second one prints the constant value of `programText`. And the last one prints the rest of the program. So `programText` will be printed twice.

```
public class SelfPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(getMyText());
    }
    private static String[] programText = {
"public class SelfPrint {",
"    public static void main(String[] args) {",
"        System.out.print(getMyText());",
"    }",
"    private static String[] programText = {",
"    };",
"    private static String getMyText() {",
"        char q = 34, c = 44;",
"        String n = System.lineSeparator();",
"        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();",
"        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)",
"            sb.append(programText[i]).append(n);",
"        for (int i = 0; i < programText.length; i++)",
"            sb.append(q + programText[i] + q + c).append(n);",
"        for (int i = 5; i < programText.length; i++)",
"            sb.append(programText[i]).append(n);",
"        return sb.toString();",
"    }",
"}",
    };
    private static String getMyText() {
        char q = 34, c = 44;
        String n = System.lineSeparator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            sb.append(programText[i]).append(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < programText.length; i++)
            sb.append(q + programText[i] + q + c).append(n);
        for (int i = 5; i < programText.length; i++)
            sb.append(programText[i]).append(n);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Test (on Windows11)

```
C:\temp>javac SelfPrint.java

C:\temp>java SelfPrint > out

C:\temp>diff SelfPrint.java out

C:\temp>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```